# Reading file with N lines at once in python

Tags: python, io

I am reading xyz trajectory files a lot. These files are structured in a way, that information corresponding to a time frame is stored in N lines.

I would like to write an iterator similar to:

```
file=open(...)
for line in file:
   analyze(line)
```

but reading N line at once:

```
file=Myopen(...,N=n)
for Nlines in file:
    analyze(Nlines)
```

Since the files are huge, I do not want to read the whole into memory,
but the purpose is not to gain efficiency but to make a clean and reuseable code. Of course, one could check the index%N==0, and analyze when it is true,
but I am a bit sick of writing that few lines over, and over, and over....

Comments and answers are more than appreciated!

Comment: you might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe for a generator function that does what you want:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

If you don't need to handle files that aren't an exact multiple of three lines long, you can simplify things a bit and just use `for nlines in zip(*[file]*5)` directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
file=Myopen(...,N=n)
Nlines = []
for i in range(N):
     Nlines.append(file.readline)
analyze( ''.join(Nlines) )
```